# Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I need to make my iframe height dynamically adjustable according to its content height. I am using davidjbradshaw's *iframeResizer.js* for the task.
I have added *iframeResizer.contentWindow.js* in the content page as well.
and *iFrameResizer.min.js* in iframe page.

While calling `iFrameResize({log:false});` I am getting the following error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined

I have tried calling `iFrameResize({log:false})` on onload of iframe as well but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you've not added the iFrameResizer.min.js in iframe page. Just check the file name and path. Make sure that iFrameResizer.min.js is loaded.

Also, check the below link

http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/#troubleshooting

Comment: I can see the iFrameResizer.min.js in the source. It is getting loaded but somehow it is unable to call function.
iFrameResize({log:false}).
I am using require.js in my project . As iFrameResizer.min.js is also using some "define" keyword, I am forced to think is that the reason?

Comment: Same issue here. When I add the iframeResizer.min.js, I'm specifically waiting for onload to call iFrameResize() and still getting undefined. Also can confirm it's loaded into the browser.